# Fooocus WebUI always wants to download a file to default folder

Tags: json, artificial-intelligence, stable-diffusion

please I have problem with Fooocus WebUI for Stable Diffusion. It always trying download file `juggernautXL_v8Rundiffusion.safetensors` or `realisticStockPhoto_v20.safetensors` into folder `C:\AI\models\checkpoints`

I'm not sure why, because I have all in SDXL subfolder (checkpoints and loras). My directory structure looks like this:

```bash
$ find /c/AI/models -type f
/c/AI/models/checkpoints/SDXL/juggernautXL_v8Rundiffusion.safetensors
/c/AI/models/checkpoints/SDXL/realisticStockPhoto_v20.safetensors
/c/AI/models/loras/SDXL/anima_pencil-XL-v1.5.0.safetensors
/c/AI/models/loras/SDXL/SDXL_FILM_PHOTOGRAPHY_STYLE_BetaV0.4.safetensors
/c/AI/models/loras/SDXL/sd_xl_offset_example-lora_1.0.safetensors
```

And `config.txt` looks like this:

```json
{
  "path_checkpoints": "C:\\AI\\models\\checkpoints",
  "path_loras": "C:\\AI\\models\\loras",
  "path_embeddings": "C:\\AI\\apps\\Fooocus\\Fooocus\\models\\embeddings",
  "path_vae_approx": "C:\\AI\\apps\\Fooocus\\Fooocus\\models\\vae_approx",
  "path_upscale_models": "C:\\AI\\apps\\Fooocus\\Fooocus\\models\\upscale_models",
  "path_inpaint": "C:\\AI\\apps\\Fooocus\\Fooocus\\models\\inpaint",
  "path_controlnet": "C:\\AI\\apps\\Fooocus\\Fooocus\\models\\controlnet",
  "path_clip_vision": "C:\\AI\\apps\\Fooocus\\Fooocus\\models\\clip_vision",
  "path_fooocus_expansion": "C:\\AI\\apps\\Fooocus\\Fooocus\\models\\prompt_expansion\\fooocus_expansion",
  "path_outputs": "C:\\AI\\apps\\Fooocus\\Fooocus\\outputs",

  "default_model": "SDXL\\juggernautXL_v8Rundiffusion.safetensors",
  "default_refiner": "SDXL\\realisticStockPhoto_v20.safetensors",
  "default_refiner_switch": 0.9,
  "default_cfg_scale": 2.0,
  "default_sample_sharpness": 4.0,
  "default_styles": [
    "Photo Iphone Photographic",
    "Fooocus Enhance",
    "Fooocus Sharp"
  ],
  "default_prompt": "(Photorealistic:1.4), ((Masterpiece)), solo, 1girl, full body shot of 35 year old Slovakian woman, long black hair, green eyes, symmetric eyes, (arrogant look:0.8), lust smile, facing to the viewer, pale skin, (pace with pores:0.6)",
  "default_prompt_negative": "bad quality, average quality, low quality, disproportionate body, disfigured limbs, fused fingers, anime, 3d, cartoon, watermark, text, logo, ",
  "default_performance": "Quality",
  "default_image_number": 4,
  "default_max_image_number": 32,
  "default_aspect_ratio": "896*1152"
}
```

**JSON** file is correct, no errors and default model which i want to use in `exec ./run.bat` or `exec ./run_realistic.bat` looks like this

```bash
$ cat run.bat
.\python_embeded\python.exe -s Fooocus\entry_with_update.py
pause

$ cat run_realistic.bat

.\python_embeded\python.exe -s Fooocus\entry_with_update.py --preset realistic
pause
```

Also `realistic` preset looking for right folder

```json
{
    "default_model": "SDXL\\realisticStockPhoto_v20.safetensors",
    "default_refiner": "",
    "default_refiner_switch": 0.5,
    "default_loras": [
        [
            "SDXL\\SDXL_FILM_PHOTOGRAPHY_STYLE_BetaV0.4.safetensors",
            0.25
        ],
        [
            "None",
            1.0
        ],
        [
            "None",
            1.0
        ],
        [
            "None",
            1.0
        ],
        [
            "None",
            1.0
        ]
    ],
    "default_cfg_scale": 3.0,
    "default_sample_sharpness": 2.0,
    "default_sampler": "dpmpp_2m_sde_gpu",
    "default_scheduler": "karras",
    "default_performance": "Speed",
    "default_prompt": "",
    "default_prompt_negative": "unrealistic, saturated, high contrast, big nose, painting, drawing, sketch, cartoon, anime, manga, render, CG, 3d, watermark, signature, label",
    "default_styles": [
        "Fooocus V2",
        "Fooocus Photograph",
        "Fooocus Negative"
    ],
    "default_aspect_ratio": "896*1152",
    "checkpoint_downloads": {
        "realisticStockPhoto_v20.safetensors": "https://huggingface.co/lllyasviel/fav_models/resolve/main/fav/realisticStockPhoto_v20.safetensors"
    },
    "embeddings_downloads": {},
    "lora_downloads": {
        "SDXL_FILM_PHOTOGRAPHY_STYLE_BetaV0.4.safetensors": "https://huggingface.co/lllyasviel/fav_models/resolve/main/fav/SDXL_FILM_PHOTOGRAPHY_STYLE_BetaV0.4.safetensors"
    },
    "previous_default_models": ["realisticStockPhoto_v10.safetensors"]
}
```

Thanks for any advice wehere could be a problem

I have solution, if I set, in `config.txt` the path checkpoints to

```
"path_checkpoints": "C:\\AI\\models\\checkpoints\\SDXL",
```

Then is it OK. But this is not correct solution because I have also SDXL_Turbo models or Lightning models or classic SD15 models.

Any possible how to disable download it or check the paths with subfolders when I have it in --preset json?

Thanks for any advice

Martin

Answer (score 0):

OK. I got it. You must change the `checkpoint_downloads` as well. In my case the line in preset

```json
"checkpoint_downloads": {
        "realisticStockPhoto_v20.safetensors": "https://huggingface.co/lllyasviel/fav_models/resolve/main/fav/realisticStockPhoto_v20.safetensors"
    },
```

must be

```json
"checkpoint_downloads": {
        "SDXL\\realisticStockPhoto_v20.safetensors": "https://huggingface.co/lllyasviel/fav_models/resolve/main/fav/realisticStockPhoto_v20.safetensors"
    },
```

for follow the same subdirectory scheme